# subprocess calling rsync hangs after possible buffer fill

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, rsync

```
[root@devdbadmin bin]# uname -a
Linux devdbadmin 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@devdbadmin bin]# python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.0
```

I have a issue I have been debugging unsuccessfully, I am attempting to run multiple rsync commands via subprocess and python.  I have spent a great deal of time reading about all the gotchas and have not been able to get a clean run.  I am not concerned about the output of rsync, nor am I concerned about stderr/stdout.  I am just looking for the return code for success or failure.  What happens is the first rsync will work and occasionally the second command will work, at any point the child process will stop intermittently in what shows as a timeout according to strace:

```
select(4, NULL, [3], [3], {60, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

I have narrowed this down to subprocess since I am able to run the commands in the shell with no issues.  I think the buffers are filling and causing the child to deadlock or wait.  According to the manual I read this:

> Warning
>
> This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the
>   child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks
>   waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate()
>   to avoid that

Thing is, I am not using pipe in my subprocess command so I am baffled. I tried having python get called with -u for un buffered and I have tried to have rsync -stbuf=L for line.  Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
subfolders = ['7/centosplus/x86_64',
              '7/updates/x86_64',
              '7/x86_64',
              'epel/7/x86_64',
              'remi/x86_64',
              'php56/x86_64',
              'nginx']

princeton_commands = [['rsync -az rsync://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/ 7/x86_64/'],
                      ['rsync -az rsync://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/centos/7/updates/x86_64/ 7/updates/x86_64/'],
                      ['rsync -az rsync://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/centos/7/centosplus/x86_64/ 7/centosplus/x86_64/']]

def makefolders(root_dir, subfolders):
    concat_path = functools.partial(os.path.join, root_dir)
    dir_list = list(map(concat_path, subfolders))
    logger.info('CREATING DIRECTORIES: %s' % dir_list)
    for dirs in dir_list:
        os.makedirs(dirs)

def execute_jobs(cmd):
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmds,shell=True, check=True)
        logger.info('rsync Success: %s' % cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.critical('%s FATAL: Command failed with error: %s' % (cmd,e))

def main():
    if os.path.exists(root_dir):
        logger.critical('PATH EXISTS, manually run [ rm -rf %s ] to proceed...' % root_dir)
        sys.exit(1)

    makefolders(root_dir, subfolders)
    os.chdir(root_dir)

    for cmds in princeton_commands:
        execute_jobs(cmds)

main()
```

I know that linux has a pipr buffer, however I am not using -v verbose on my rsync commands so I am not getting much output back that would fill this buffer, I am also not using pipe in subprocess as previously mentioned. I am using free to see if memory fills and I am not seeing anything relevant.

Important to mention, I have tried multiple mirror hosts thinking I was being throttled or blocked, but rsync will stop on any host I try once it gets around halfway through.

EDIT:

```
Here is the strace and lsof of the process stuck:
root     29195  8.6  0.0 117488  2084 pts/0    S    10:47   1:54  |                       |           \_ rsync -az rsync://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/centos/7/updates/x86_64/ 7/updates/x86_64/

[root@devdbadmin bin]# strace -p 29195
strace: Process 29195 attached
select(4, [3], [], [3], {52, 716623})   = 0 (Timeout)
select(4, [3], [], [3], {60, 0}^Cstrace: Process 29195 detached

[root@devdbadmin bin]# lsof -p 29195 -ad  4,3
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
rsync   29195 root    3u  IPv4 1686385      0t0      TCP devdbadmin.afs:40500->mirror.math.princeton.edu:rsync (ESTABLISHED)
rsync   29195 root    4u   REG   253,3   786432 10755679 /u01/repo/monthly/CentOS7/2018-02/7/updates/x86_64/drpms/.python-perf-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7_3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64.drpm.g7XODd
```

Comment: Many things here don’t make sense.  You’re passing a list to `run()`, but it has one element that is a shell command and you haven’t set `shell=True`.  Then you try to catch `CalledProcessError` without setting `check=True`.  And your `select` isn’t waiting on stdout/stderr, which are inherited anyway.  And buffering options are irrelevant if you’re planning to ignore the output anyway...

Comment: If I run (on Linux, as you mentioned) `subprocess.run("date +%s")` **or**  `subprocess.run(["date +%s"])`, I get `ENOENT` trying to find a binary whose name has all 8 characters (which raises an exception regardless of `check`).  Are you _sure_ this is the code you're using?

Comment: `+%s` is not shell-specific (like `$HOME` and `>/dev/null`), it's just an argument like your `-az` etc.  You shouldn't be able to use the code you gave to do anything at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162820/discussion-between-davis-herring-and-jaysunn).

Comment: You are right @davis I have shell=True and check=True in my code, I pasted it wrong.  I have edited it and now I am still facing the timeout issue. You mention the `select` isn't waiting on stdout/stderr, can you suggest a way to debug what it is waiting on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and learning a lot about strace/rsync,subprocess, I reached out to one of the admins of the official mirrors and explained my situation.  They asked me to start my sync off hours, between 12AM to 8AM. Once doing this the rsyncs completed as normal.  So I am thinking the issue was sender ran out of rsync slots or resources to send the data.  The strace output shows it waiting on a fd that is not getting data.  I hope this helps anyone and I hope someone can confirm this by looking at my strace.